# JPA Query with Case condition

Tags: sql, jpa

```
(Case a.statusCd When 'ln' then 'loan' else a.status_cd end) as statusCd
```

Why this jpa query returns an error?

The whole query string is

```
String qryString = "select"
                + " a.biblioId, " // 0
                + " a.copyId, " // 1
                + " a.copyDescr, "// 2
                + " a.employeeId, "// 3
                + " (Case a.statusCd When 'ln' then 'loan' else a.status_cd end) as statusCd, "// 4
                + " a.statusBeginDt, "// 5
                + " a.libListingCopyId, "// 6
                + " a.barcodeNbr, " // 7
                + " b.title, " // 8
                + " b.author " // 9
                + " from LibListingCopy a, LibListing b " + " where  "
                + curStmt + "and " + authStmt
                + "and a.biblioId = b.biblioId and a.siteId=b.siteId and "
                + bibStmt + " and  " + cpyStmt + " and " + libCodeStmt
                + " and " + accnNbrStmt;
```

Comment: please post your whole query, what is 'a'?

Comment: @OBL Tobl please find the whole query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your query, there are two seperate fieldnames for the same filed i think:

```
(Case a.statusCd When 'ln' then 'loan' else a.status_cd end) as statusCd
```

should be

```
(Case a.statusCd When 'ln' then 'loan' else a.statusCd end) as statusCd
```

or (for the other possibility)

```
(Case a.status_cd When 'ln' then 'loan' else a.status_cd end) as statusCd
```

So the failure may be the spelling of your field **a.status_cd / a.statusCd**